# ios + xcode + PhoneGapDelegate.h not found issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Mac OS X 10.7.4
Xcode 4.5.2

When I am trying to build my xcode application I get an error: **'PhoneGap/PhoneGapDelegate.h' file not found**.

I was searching a lot of time. But without success.

Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to install phonegap 1.2
my current version of phonegap is 2, but it needs 1.2